# Looking up column value in df1 based on criteria in df2

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df y1 in which is a column 'col_min_val'. In this df I have stored the column in which a minimum value is stored (could be anything from y1 to y50).

I want to get the corresponding value out of a second df named ideal_df_test based on the column name stored in 'col_min_val' in y1.

Let's say for y1

| x | col_min_val |
| --- | --- |
| -20.0 | y10 |
| -19.9 | y23 |
| -19.8 | y10 |

ideal_df_test: for x = -20.0 I want to go to row with x = -20.0 and the column = y10 and get the value that is stored in there.

I tried this code:

```
for i in range(len(y1)):
    y_ideal['y1'] = ideal_df_test[y1['col_min_val'].values[i]]
```

But it is not working correctly, as it is storing only the value from one column. In my example, everything would have the values based on y10.

Where am I going wrong here?

EDIT:

ideal_df_test looks like this:

| x | y1 | ... | y50 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -20.0 | 2.3 | ... | 0.1102 |
| -19.9 | -10.32 | ... | 23.05 |
| -19.8 | 7500.0035 | ... | -1.2345 |

Expected output:

| x | y_from ideal_df_test |
| --- | --- |
| -20.0 | 10 |
| -19.9 | 7889.123 |
| -19.8 | 4.35 |

Where 10 and 4.35 would be the values stored in y10. 7889.123 the value stored in y23.

Comment: Can you please provide samples of both dataframes?

Comment: you are trying to have a function that returns a value from col_min_val or you're mapping the col-Min-val to the values in y_ideal? In later case you don't need a for loop. please share more details and the expected output in reproducing the problem

Comment: @Jacob  I added samples of the dataframes.

Comment: @Naveed I added more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
df.set_index('DICT_KEY_COLUMN').to_dict()['DICT_VALUE_COLUMN']
```

This will create a dictionary where the key is the index you set and the value is the 2nd column specified.

Comment: I don't understand how to use this. Could you elaborate on your suggestion a little more? Thanks for your input.

Comment: it took me a while but I figured out what you meant. I think it's working :)